# $g \varphi = \varphi^2 g$, $g$ injective implies that $\varphi$ and $\varphi^2$ have the same kernel, image, eigenvalue and eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that $\varphi$ and $g$ are linear transformations from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g \circ \varphi = \varphi^2 \circ g$ and $g$ is injective. Show that $\varphi$ and $\varphi^2$ have the same kernel, image, eigenvalues and eigenspaces.

1. I think I need some validity check on the first part.

> As $g$ is injective on finite dimensional vector space, it is in fact bijective, hence invertible. So I somehow rewrite it as
> $$
> g \varphi g^{-1} = \varphi^2
> $$
> so $\varphi$ and $\varphi^2$ are "similar". As similar transformations have the same rank and $\ker \varphi \subseteq \ker \varphi^2$, their kernel, hence image, must be equal.

2. The problem now lies in the eigenvalues and eigenspaces. I know that the eigenvalues of $\varphi$ and $\varphi^2$ will agree because similarity, but I don't know about whether the eigenspaces will agree or not.

Comment: Do you mean $g \varphi g^{-1} = \varphi^2$?

Comment: yes, my mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that every eigenvector of $\varphi$ must in turn be an eigenvector of $\varphi^2$. Then, note that because $\varphi^2$ is similar to $\varphi$, the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces of $\varphi^2$ must be equal to that of $\varphi$. Thus, $\varphi^2$ can't have "more eigenvectors" that $\varphi$.